# get a line break / new line in excel file with r xlsx

Tags: r, excel, newline, xlsx, line-breaks

I want to get a new line in my excel result such as i would get by going into the cell and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### data + code

```
df <- data.frame(a="Funny\\nNot",b="rofl\nlol",c="hihi\rh3h3")

xlsx::write.xlsx(df,file = "df.xlsx")
```

Comment: Setting the columns to [wrap text](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/carriage_return_within_a_cell_in_microsoft_excel.htm) and `\n` should work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the package `xlsx`:

Remove the escape `'\'` from column `a`:

```
df <- data.frame(a="Funny\nNot",b="rofl\nlol",c="hihi\rh3h3")

library(xlsx)
```

Create workbook and sheet objects:

```
wb <- createWorkbook() 
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="sheet1")
```

Add dataframe:

```
addDataFrame(df, sheet)
```

get row 2, column B from the wb/sheet:

```
rows <- getRows(sheet, rowIndex = 2)

cell_b_2 <- getCells(rows, colIndex = 2)[[1]]
```

Create a `CellStyle` that sets `Wrap Text` in Excel:

```
cs <- CellStyle(wb, alignment = Alignment(wrapText = TRUE))
```

Apply it to the cell:

```
setCellStyle(cell_b_2, cs)
```

Save the workbook:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, 'df.xlsx')
```

The resulting workbook looks like this:

[image: excel-output]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @lukeA for name dropping.

When I use `wrap text` for cells containing `"\n"`. I get the desired outcome.

Here is the code I used:

```
wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook("df.xlsx")
sheets <- xlsx::getSheets(wb)
sheet  <- sheets[[1]]                  # get specific sheet
rows   <- xlsx::getRows(sheet)         # get rows
cells  <- xlsx::getCells(rows)         # get cells
values <- lapply(cells, xlsx::getCellValue) # extract the cell values


wrapStyle <- xlsx::CellStyle(wb) + xlsx::Alignment(horizontal=NULL, vertical=NULL, wrapText=T,
                              rotation=0, indent=0)

lapply(names(cells),function(c)if(values[[c]] %>% grepl("\\n",.))xlsx::setCellStyle(cells[[c]],wrapStyle))

xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,"dfWrap.xlsx")
```

Answer (score -2):

\n will break the line and add logic to wrap the cell